# Static variable: Construction happens after usage

Tags: c++

I am doing some testing in Visual Studio 2013 in a console application. Static variables are involved and I'm seeing some strange behavior. There are main issue is the static `Printer` member of the `GenericFactory` template class is constructed *after* I use it (inside its `Register` function)!

The rules regarding global / static variables and initialization order are very complex so could someone help me understand what is going on wrong here? Code is below.

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Main Function\n";
}
```

**GenericFactory.hpp:**

```
#pragma once

#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Printer
{
public:
   Printer()
   {
      std::cout << "Printer class created\n";
   }

   void Stuff()
   {
      std::cout << "Printer Stuff, Address " << (int)this << "\n";
   }
};

template<typename Key>
class GenericFactory
{
public:

   static Key const& Register(Key const& key)
   {
      GenericFactory::s_printer.Stuff();
      std::cout << "Registered: " << key << "\n";
      return key;
   }

private:
   static Printer s_printer;
};

template<typename Key>
Printer GenericFactory<Key>::s_printer;
```

**StringFactory.hpp:**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include "GenericFactory.hpp"

using StringFactory = GenericFactory<int>;
```

**test1.cpp:**

```
#include "StringFactory.hpp"

namespace Other
{
   static auto key = StringFactory::Register(100);
}
```

**test2.cpp:**

```
#include "StringFactory.hpp"

namespace Other
{
   static auto key = StringFactory::Register(200);
}
```

Output I get after running the application above:

```
Printer Stuff, Address 3422532
Registered: 100
Printer class created
Printer Stuff, Address 3422532
Registered: 200
Main Function
```

Note that `"Printer Stuff, ..."` is printed before `"Printer class created"`. Am I going insane here?

Comment: Is there any chance you can simplify your example?

Comment: @Brian I have simplified it slightly, let me know if that helps.

Comment: If you must use global variables, follow some singleton pattern which protects against some common issues. If the class has no non-static members, why is it a class at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assuming an order of construction for the global variables.  This is not a good approach.
Try changing it to something like (not cleanest, but makes the point):

```
template<typename Key>
class GenericFactory
{
   static Printer& printer()
   {
       static Printer s_printer;
       return s_Printer;
   }
public:


   Key const& Register(Key const& key) // removed static here.
   {
      printer().Stuff();
      std::cout << "Registered: " << key << "\n";
      return key;
   }

};
```

EDIT:

Here is a typical pattern I use for singletons that do not require the multi-threaded double lock protection:

```
#include <memory>

class MySingletonClass
{
public:
  static MySingletonClass* instance()
  {
    static std::unique_ptr<MySingletonClass> ptr(new MySingletonClass);
    return ptr.get();
  }

  // Public functions here

private:
  friend struct std::default_delete<MySingletonClass>;
  // Hide these to avoid unintentional copy
  MySingletonClass() {}
  ~MySingletonClass() {}
  MySingletonClass(const MySingletonClass&) {}
  MySingletonClass& operator= (const MySingletonClass&) { return *this; }
};
```

If you want to add thread safety as well, you can find many articles by searching:
https://www.google.com/search?q=singleton+c%2B%2B+double+checked+locking

Comment: Nice idea. What, in your opinion, would be cleaner? Since you mentioned not the cleanest (which says to me you aren't happy with it, but with a little more thought perhaps a better solution could be found).

Comment: I usually use a more nicely structured Singleton.  There are lot of examples of singleton pattern implementation.  I'll try to edit and add above some example.